# Where can I find the reason for a civicrm.org extension not showing up in the list of managed extension of our site?

Tags: extension

We have a test site with Drupal 9.5.3, CiviCRM 5.58.1 and PHP 8.1.11.
A couple of the extensions that we use on our current productive site (Drupal 7.94, CiviCRM 5.57.1 and PHP 7.4.32) do not show up in the list of managed extension of our test site, for instance:

- de.systopia.birthdays
- de.systopia.osm
- com.ginkgostreet.mosaicotoolbarconfig (which should be replaced by mosaicoextras when that extension becomes available).

I imagine that there is currently no version of those extensions compatible with CiviCRM 5.58.1. Would it be conceivable to add a page in the extension management of CiviCRM that would explain why any given extension didn't make it in the list of automatically installable extensions and whether there is a timeline for inclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/publish/#automated-distribution

They just haven't applied for review/been reviewed. On your other sites you must have downloaded them manually into the extensions folder.